# Splunk regex to match part of url string

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm trying to use Splunk to search for all base path instances of a specific url (and maybe plot it on a chart afterwards).

Here are some example urls and the part I want to match for:

```sh
http://some-url.com/first/  # match "first"
http://some-url.com/first/second/ # match "first"
http://some-url.com/first/second/third/  # match "first"
```

Here's the regex I'm using, which works fine:

```
http:\/\/some-url\.com\/(.*?)\/
```

What should my Splunk search be to extract the desired text? Is this even possible in Splunk?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's always `com`.

Using [rex](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/7.2.7/SearchReference/rex):

```
index= and other stuff | rex field=(if not _raw) "\.com/(?<match> \w+)/" | table match
```

Answer (score 0):

To match any URL (.com or not), you can use the following command.

```
index=... | rex field=_raw "http(s)?://[^/]+/(?<match>[^/]+)"
```

This will match things such as

```
http://splunk.com/first/
https://simonduff.net/first/
https://splunk.com/first/middle/last
https://splunk.com/first
```